# Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1. I am getting error while syncing project with gradle files. Build variant not showing

Gradle version as per gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip

build.gradle file

```
buildscrpit{
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing gradle version to 7.5 and 8.0 but did not work